# Interpretation of semantics of queue algebra

Tags: programming-languages, algebra

I am trying to understand the semantics for stack algebra and queue algebra as introduced in section 8.5, "Specification Algebras" of textbook *Software Engineering 1, Abstraction and Modelling*, Dines Bjørner, 1st ed.

Queue Algebra is given as:

$\textbf{hide}$
$\hspace{1em}dq, rq\ \ \textbf{in}$
$\textbf{class}$
$\hspace{1em}\textbf{type}$
$\hspace{2em}E, Q$
$\hspace{1em}\textbf{value}$
$\hspace{2em}empty{:}\ \textbf{Unit}\to Q, \ is\_empty{:}\ Q\to \textbf{Bool}$
$\hspace{2em}enq{:}\ E\to Q \to Q, \ deq{:}\ Q \overset{\sim}{\rightarrow} (Q\times E)$
$\hspace{2em}dq{:}\ Q \overset{\sim}{\rightarrow} E, \ rq{:}\ Q \overset{\sim}{\rightarrow} Q$
$\hspace{1em}\textbf{axiom}$
$\hspace{2em}is\_empty(empty()), \ deq(empty()) \equiv \textbf{chaos},$
$\hspace{2em}dq(empty())\equiv \textbf{chaos}, \ rq(empty()) \equiv \textbf{chaos}$
$\hspace{2em}\text{forall}~e,e'{:}E, \ q{:}Q\ \cdot$
$\hspace{3em}\sim is\_empty(enq(e)(q)),$
$\hspace{3em}\vdots$
$\hspace{3em}rq(enq(e)(enq(e')(q))) \equiv enq(e)(rq(enq(e')(q)))$
$\hspace{3em}\vdots$
$\textbf{end}$

**Edit**:

**Question**: what is meant by $rq(enq(e)(enq(e')(q))) \equiv enq(e)(rq(enq(e')(q)))$

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  If you have multiple questions, they can be posted separately (though I suggest posting them one at a time, otherwise all of them may suffer from the same issue).

Comment: What's the context?  Where did you encounter this?  We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  You have received similar feedback before:  https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/144973/minimizing-total-penalty-from-trips-over-all-travel-days?noredirect=1#comment306183_144973

Comment: Please check your typesetting.  I find your mathematics hard to understand, with the horizontal spacing making it hard to understand the equations.

Comment: As a reminder, a question like "I am not able to understand what is going on here" is not acceptable here.  We require you to articulate a specific question, and I recommend you describe what you do understand. You have received similar feedback before: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/149256/why-we-can-not-define-factorial-in-lambda-calculus#comment312872_149256

Comment: @D.W. Thank you. I just kept one question now.

Comment: I see two questions, one about chaos and one about that equation.  I will edit this to pick one arbitrarily.  You can ask the other separately.

Comment: @D.W. Thank you. I found that chaos means cannot be evaluated.